# Creating Custom User CSS

Tags: css

I am trying to create custom user CSS for someone to use, that will remove all the extra stuff on a website they are viewing, except the body content. I figured I could use chromes inspect to get the sites CSS code, then edit it and use a custom user css extension on chrome to implement it. However the site has over 7000 lines of code in their CSS and I am still very new to CSS. Is there any simple way to make this work without having to go through 7000 lines of code?

Comment: you can change common tags css like entire html,body,divs,headings but cannot be specific about the whole site without going through that

Comment: shortly you can change font size,color,family.., background for all pages commonly like night mode,day mode

Comment: the main thing is the site i'm trying to make the custom CSS for has a ton of ads, tool bars, links etc that he simply wants to be able to go away so he can focus on the body text.

Answer (score 0):

Here is just a quick, bare-minimum, "prove of concept"-type starter of how you can achieve what you want using Firefox browser, just to get you going.

Create two files: `manifest.json` and `RemoveStuff.js`.

Put this inside `manifest.json`

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "RemoveStuff",
  "version": "1.0",

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*.google.com/*"],
      "js": ["RemoveStuff.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

and put this inside `RemoveStuff.js`

```
document.getElementById("lga").outerHTML='';
```

Now **using Firefox browser** navigate to `about:debugging`, click `Load Temporary Add-on` and select `RemoveStuff.js`. Now go to [google](http://google.com) and you shouldn't see google's logo (or whatever picture/animation they have there).

---

You can start learning about Firefox extensions [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Your_first_WebExtension), or Chrome [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted)